# Combine Columns Based Upon Another Column with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge tab-delimited file such as the following :

```
3 Line1 0 100 A
4 Line1 100 200 A
7 Line1 200 300 B
2 Line1 300 400 B
12 Line1 400 500 C
10 Line1 500 600 C
```

For all the rows that have the letters (A, B, ect), I need to combine their values based upon the number in the first column.  For example, what should be the result is below:

```
7 A
9 B
22 C
```

I am currently using Pandas + Python to figure this out.

Comment: For the result, is it going to be 7 and 9 for `A` and  `B` in example?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  I went ahead and corrected the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the df is as below:

```
   val     id  line  col1 col2
0    3  Line1     0   100    A
1    4  Line1   100   200    A
2    7  Line1   200   300    B
3    2  Line1   300   400    B
4   12  Line1   400   500    C
5   10  Line1   500   600    C
```

Then, I think you can use `groupby` followed by `sum`:

```
result_df = df.groupby('col2')['val'].sum().to_frame('Sum')
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
      Sum
col2     
A       7
B       9
C      22
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *join()* method

```
Table1.join(table2.set_index(''key"),on='key')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[3,4,7,2,12,10],'Col2':['A','A','B','B','C','C']})
df.groupby('Col2').sum()
```